# How to make canvas responsive within vuetify card

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, fabricjs, responsive

**Context:**
Hi I am trying to make canvas look responsive[mobile,tab,dekstop] using vuetify.

**Problem:**
This what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

This is what happens currently,for small screens ie. xs and sm the canvas overflows the card and flex.[image]

[image]

**This is what I have tried till now:**

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/OJWxbwV

```
:style="{ zoom: (clientSize / canvasWidth) 

this.clientSize = this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs
      ? this.$vuetify.clientWidth * 0.35
      : this.$vuetify.clientWidth * 0.157;
```

I am trying to get clientWidth with a certain custom value which I feel is not the right approach.

Not sure how to proceed further. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't figure it out as It's more a fabricjs "issue" than a vuetify...I've tried to read It's docs, but I found It hard to understand...Try getting more into the canvas and background image constructor options...It might have something about relative width (%). There is a "cssOnly" (boolean) also that might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it. I am almost near to the solution i think tried the fabric approach here https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/OJWxbwV ,