# How to prevent canvas from overflowing the card and make it responsive in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, fabricjs, responsive

**Context:**

Hi, I am trying to use fabricjs canvas within vuetify and make it look responsive in all the screens.
But currently, I am facing an issue where the canvas is not re-sizing based on card,it overflows the card instead.
I have tried using v-responsive but it does not apply the aspect ratio to canvas, could be, the way I am using it is not the right way.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

**This is what is happening now**

[image]

**This is what i am trying to achieve**

**Structure**

[image]

**Mock:**

[image]

**Code**

This is what i have tried till now.

```
<v-layout>
  <v-flex xs12>
    <v-container class="red" fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex xs3 sm3 md3 class="ma-2" class="purple">
          <v-card flat tile class="yellow">
            <v-card-title
              id="fabric-canvas-wrapper"
              class="green pb-0 justify-center"
            >
              <v-responsive aspect-ratio="4/3" class="mx-auto px-3">
                <canvas id="c"> </canvas>
              </v-responsive>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text class="blue text-xs-center py-0">
              <p class=".body-2 pa-2 text-truncate">Kangaroo Valley Safari</p>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/OJWOPBo

Comment: Is this a different question than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990481/how-to-make-canvas-responsive-within-vuetify-card)?

Comment: why not using fixed width based on the canvas?
https://codepen.io/Denizzer/pen/JjEOGQN?editors=1010

Comment: @Zim Both are similar, elaborated about the problem in more details here.

Comment: I have tried using fabricjs approach https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/OJWxbwV but needed more insights on whether there is vuetify approach to it,

Comment: Deniz The canvas will be used on the mobile screen as well. so fixed-width might not show the canvas properly.

Comment: @A.D think about the size. your canvas seems really small. there is no mobile device out there smaller then width 320px. even if so, you could go with a media query to handle this for special cases

Comment: maybe you have to rerender the canvas on each resize of the screen. like you use  window.eventListner('resize') and handle the size of the canvas manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A canvas element can be sized arbitrarily by a style sheet, its bitmap is then subject to the 'object-fit' CSS property.

[Source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#attr-canvas-width)

The width/height of the canvas element are different from the width/height of the canvas element's bitmap. This means that you can use only CSS styles to fix this problem.

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dq0mfkbt/6/)

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio you can use the padding trick.

```css
.canvas-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%; // for 1:1 ratio
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dq0mfkbt/10/)